# Raspberry Pi install Metasploit

Tags: linux, ruby, metasploit

I will install Metasploit on my Raspi with Raspbian, but I get an error. I don't know how I can fix it, PLEASE HELP ME
The Error is:

> root@raspberrypi:/opt/metasploit-framework# ./msfconsole
>   Could not find gem 'metasploit-concern (>= 0) ruby', which is required by gem 'metasploit-framework (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.
>   root@raspberrypi:/opt/metasploit-framework#

Comment: Is ruby installed?

Comment: Yes, ruby is installed

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to below links:
https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-metasploit-0167798/
Note: update your ruby >= 2.2 before doing that steps. pls refer to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49565/how-to-install-ruby-2-1-9

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.